# on tap of background change the background color to selected color

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

[image]

i want to add one functionality in my app like user can change the color of similar portion of background color where he touch.also user can undo the events, there is one application called **[wall Pentair](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/wall-painter/id396799182?mt=8)** i exact want same functionality.

i don't know where to start it, which frameworks have to use for it.

I would highly appreciate any help with this please.

Answer (score 1):

you can get color of pixel where you touch in background. after that replace that color with another color. 
To detect color i used ColorPickerImageView class.
you can download that class from this link
https://www.assembla.com/code/GeoBattle/subversion/nodes/xcode/Classes/ColorPickerImageView.m?rev=189

this may helps you

Comment: thanks for replay, i get the color of touched point but getting problem in identifying the same color pixels of image so i can set that color to them.

Comment: you have to check each pixel of an image, if pixel has same color as pixel of background where you were touch  then replace it with another color.

Comment: thanks for replay, i  not that much good in cg graphics can you please   give some code or sample for that

Comment: I am not sure, but you can use for loop to check color of each pixel. ex.  for iphone , you have to do something like for(int i=0;i<320;i++){ for(int j=0;j<480;j++){ //get color of pixel at i,j and if it is color which you touch then replace it }}

Comment: i try this its tacking over the minuet to check all the pixels.i things there is something another way to do this.

Comment: i am not sure, that there is another way for that. if you get any thing please update it here, i also want to do the same thing. Meanwhile if for loop is working for you, you can use activity indicator if it take time for checking all pixel of an image.